# Using Tikz in Beamer with arrow pointing improperly

Tags: beamer, tikz-arrows

I intent to point the arrow to $A = B$, but the arrow comes from outside of the slide. Why that? Here it is the code

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amstext,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amsbsy}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
My equation:
\begin{gather*}
A = B \tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-.5ex] \node (n1) {};
\qquad \tikz[baseline]{
\node[fill=blue!20,opacity=.6,anchor=base] (t1) {$\substack{\text{{\tiny{\color{blue}This is}}} \\ \text{{\tiny{\color{blue}my equation}}}}$};}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->,blue,opacity=.6]<1-> (n1) edge [] (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{gather*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nodes across different tikz pictures, you need the `remember picture` option.

That being said:

- you could simplify the `t1` node a lot. Using math mode to stack the text above each other seems very cumbersome.
- you should really clean up your preamble. Many of the packages are outdated and the .log file will tell you this after each compilation. Also don't need to load all the ams* package, as beamer does this automatically.
- not sure if this is your actual image, or just a shorted example, but I think it would be much easier to draw all three components in a single picture, then tikz can properly position the elements for you.
- you might also want to have a look at the tikzmarks library

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

%\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{amstext,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amsbsy}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
My equation:
\begin{gather*}
A = B 
\tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-.5ex] \node (n1) {};
\qquad 
\tikz[baseline=0.5ex,remember picture]{
  \node[fill=blue!20,opacity=.6,anchor=base,align=center,font=\color{blue}\tiny] (t1) {This is\\ my equation};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw<1->[->,blue,opacity=.6] (n1) -- (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{gather*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is only to add colored node with two line text in equation, then try the following (simple) suggestion:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \usecolortheme{crane}
    \setbeamercovered{dynamic}
    \setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
My equation:
\[
A = B
    \quad\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex] \draw[blue, ->, shorten >=3pt]  (0,0) -- ++ (1,0) 
                                        node[fill=blue!20,align=center,font=\tiny, right] 
                                            {This is\\ my equation};
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]